# Beach fishing - Should I get waders or long rod to cast further into the sea?

Tags: fishing, sea, beach

Many beaches where I want to do surf fishing (from shore) are almost flat for many feet into the sea. Some of the beaches have a steep slope into the sea. I hope to catch striped bass, perch or anything else other than sharks and stingrays.

So, I thought of getting waders to increase my casting range. With waders, I could walk a few feet into the shallow water and cast further into the sea at low or high tide.

Is it a good idea to use waders to increase casting range ? Instead of that, should I get a very long ( say 14 feet +) rod to cast further ? Should I get both long rod and waders ?

Answer (score 5):

It has been a while since I actually did fishing on a beach, but when I do, it is always with someone.

We usually get there early enough so we can get some bait for fishing (sea worms from under the rocks).

For getting your line farther out into the ocean, you could go with either suggestion you mentioned. I could suggest getting a longer rod, as you  would have better balance and movement than going into the water.

Nevertheless, I would like to throw out a third possibility to you. If you are fishing with a friend, get him to hold onto your rod  as he points it in the direction you would like to cast, keeping the bail open while you **throw the line out by hand**!

**What? Throwing the line out by hand!**

Take the slack part of you line and place yourself several meters away from your companion and start circling the end of your line over your head with the weights and baits. As the speed of your line turns faster, you should be able to detect an increasing buzzing sound around you. When the speed of your "lasso" is at its maximum, simply let it go in the direction you would like your line to travel in. Believe me this little trick will get your line much further out than any 14 foot rod. It works wonders. On occasion, I have done this without a friend, by simply placing my rod handle into a holder which I anchored into the sand. However I find that a friend holding your rod works better.

[image: Lasso]

Cast your line out like a cowboy uses his lasso!

Your distance will be amazing.

Comment: wow ! thanks. I did not think of that. I'll try this out soon and see.

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree with Ken Graham. With a 10' surf rod, I can cast 2-3 ounces 100yds or more. I don't know anyone who could throw the same lure that far - even with the "lasso" effect. The first reason is that with the lasso method, the radius of your orbit is limited by the length of your arm and your strength. With a 10' rod, the radius STARTS at about 10' and then extends out by however much line you've got out past the tip. The lure velocities are going to be MUCH greater with the rod. Factor in an even longer rod that is designed to load and throw the lure and ..